Degree of degeneracy of energy levels and irreducible representations of Hamiltonian symmetry group
In case the Hamiltonian of a system has some non-trivial symmetry regarding the physical space, let's assume symmetry that can be described by a finite symmetry group (e.g. a point group symmetry) one can see the possible degeneracies of eigenstates of the Hamiltionan from the characters of the irreducible representations of the group.
The dimension of the subspaces of the eigenfunctions, i.e. the degree of the degeneracy then is related to the dimension of the irreducible representation according to which the respective eigenfunctions transform.
The thing I do not understand is why pairs of complex conjugate characters correspond to 2-dimensional subspaces = 2-fold degeneracies. A simple example would be a threefold axis symmetry of the Hamiltonian (isomorphic to the cyclic group of order 3). Here two-fold degeneracy in the energy levels occurs but the irreps transform like a (single = "1d") complex number.
Grateful for any comments.
